# Do cats and dogs repel bugs and mice?

Tags: dogs, cats

Can we keep cats an dogs as pet for repelling bugs and mice naturally?

Comment: I am familiar with the relationship between cats and mice, but I have never heard of dog or cats repelling bugs.  Can you expand on how you think they might repel bugs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been scientifically proven that healthy mice naturally fear the smell of cats, http://www.bbc.com/news/10117428 so yes, having a cat in your house will repel mice to some degree.  I can tell you from personal experience, it's not 100 percent effective in keeping mice out.  If your cat has areas of the house it doesn't go into, it's smell won't be as strong, and its also known that mice infected with toxoplasmosis no longer fear the smell of cats. http://www.nature.com/news/parasite-makes-mice-lose-fear-of-cats-permanently-1.13777. As for dogs and bugs, I'm unaware of any studies on that.

Answer (score 3):

They definitely don't repel bugs, though cats may appreciate bugs as toys.

Mice... Again they're probably more likely to kill the mice than to simply scare them away.

Comment: My kitten is a certified pest control professional, the only downside is having to clean up all the cricket/cockroach bodies :P

Comment: @JustDoIt Same for one of our Huskies: Bugs are squished with a frontal nose stab and optional picking up and dropping. No longer moving critters are left alone.